# Representing tree structures via FFI in Rust

Tags: tree, rust, ffi

I'm new to Rust and have picked a project that's way over my head.

I have an existing C library I want to provide Rust bindings for. The fundamental data structure of the library is a node, which can have many children and zero or one parent.

In my `sys` library, I represent the opaque pointer I get from the C lib as

```
pub enum NodeRef {}
```

Furthermore, I have these FFI declarations

```
extern {
    pub fn NodeNew() -> *mut NodeRef;
    pub fn NodeInsertChild(node: *mut NodeRef, child: *mut NodeRef, index: uint32_t);
    pub fn NodeGetParent(node: *const NodeRef) -> *mut NodeRef;
    pub fn NodeFree(node: *mut NodeRef);
}
```

Now to the hard part. I want to wrap these in a safe interface.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Node {
    reference: *mut ffi::NodeRef,
    __parent: Option<???>,
}


impl Drop for Node {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { ffi::NodeFree(self.reference) }
    }
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let node = unsafe { ffi::NodeNew() };
        assert!(!node.is_null());
        Node {
            reference: node,
            __parent: None
        }
    }

    pub fn push_front(&mut self, node: &mut Node) {
        unsafe { ffi::NodeInsertChild(self.reference, node.reference, 0) }
        node.__parent = Some(???);
    }

    pub fn parent(&self) -> Option<???> {
        self.__parent
    }

}
```

I want to represent actions for adding children and retrieving the parent of a node. However, I'm not sure how to correctly specify the lifetimes of the objects. I reckon that I need to hold on to a reference of the parent myself in order to reason about its lifetime, as returning `ffi::NodeGetParent` would lead to double-freeing a node.

Comment: In common usage, *trees* are unidirectional; *graphs* are bidirectional. *Trees* are easy to handle in Rust, *graphs* are not.

Comment: Also, don't name your member variables with leading underscores; this isn't C++. In Rust, a leading underscore indicates that a value is unused, and you should never have an unused value in a struct.

Comment: Having a backpointer to the parent does not invalidate the defining characteristic of a tree, which is that a node has only one parent, and that there are no cycles. In fact, a standard way to define trees [uses graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)). Since Rust's collection library supports a `LinkedList<T>`, bidirectional pointing must be possible.